# Using SSH to tunnel over two hops, the last of which is connected through a reverse ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I would like to use OpenSSH to allow port forwarding over two hops, the last hop being connected through a reverse tunnel.

Here is my current setup:

1. Server B is running sshd on port 10000.  Server C is running sshd on port 20000
2. Client A connects to Server B via "normal" SSH
3. Server C opens a reverse SSH tunnel to Server B on port 30000
4. Server B connects to Server C through that reverse tunnel

What I want to do: open a port on Client A that forwards connections from Client A through Server B to Server C (over the reverse SSH tunnel established between Server B and Server C)

Here are the respective commands I'm currently using:

1. Client A connects to Server B via "normal" SSH:

   ```
    ClientAHostName $  ssh -p 10000 User@ServerBHostName
   ```
2. Server C opens a reverse SSH tunnel to Server B on port 30000:

   ```
   ServerCHostName $  ssh -p 10000 -N -R 30000:localhost:20000 User@ServerBHostName
   ```
3. Server B connects to Server C through that reverse tunnel:

   ```
   ServerBHostName $  ssh -p 30000 User@localhost
   ```

The reason I want to do this is so I can control certain services on Server C from Client A through a web browser (using a forwarded port).  Due to limitations imposed by the ISPs of Client A and Server C, I cannot connect directly from Server B (or Client A) to Server C, or from Server C to Client A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make things simpler I like to assign a port number or range to each server. Keeping what you've started with, B is 10000, C is 20000, forget about the 30000.

Setup:

```
A$ ssh -p 10000 -N -L 20000:localhost:20000 UserB@B
C$ ssh -p 10000 -N -R 20000:localhost:20000 UserB@B
```

Now you should be able to do

```
A$ ssh -p 20000 UserC@localhost
```

to get a shell on C, and assuming you want to connect to a web server running on server C port 8080:

```
A$ ssh -p 20000 -N -L 8080:localhost:8080 UserC@localhost
```

Connect to:

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked great.  Only thing I had to change was instead of using the -L command line option in the last shell command (on Client A) I had to use the -D option.  With the -L option I would get "ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host" errors and I wasn't able to solve this error with solutions around the web.  Also, I've given you credit but my score isn't high enough for it to show up.

Comment: @user522490 You asked the question, so you can check my answer as being the right one, no score needed for that :) (and I get more points for being the correct answer than I get for "only" an upvote!)

Comment: The "connection closed by remote host" can be debugged by using `ssh -vvv` and by looking in the the server logs, but if -D localhost:$port works for you then OK. Using -D *:$port will let other people on A's network connect to C, which may not be what you want.